# Why do I need PUT or DELETE Http Verbs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, http-verbs

After the release of MVC 2, I have started to check and play with the new features, but i couldn't understand what is the use of `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs.

I have searched about it and read some articles but I couldn't get it.

What is the main purpose of `DELETE` and `PUT`? Do they have any advantages over using a `GET` or `POST` method instead (even though I can handle all of the requests with GET and POST)?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343288/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-rest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941016/what-is-rest-closed

Comment: i can not understand the real life practical use either.
What is an actual scenario to use those verbs that you can not achive with get or post.
i think it is rather an philosophical aproach rather than practical usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- GET: Only function is to send information back to the client. It should be a [repeatable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) operation without side effects.
- POST: It does operations with side effects. It is [not repeatable](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/idempotency-explained) (if you POST twice, the server acts twice). After operation it should redirect to another page to show the results using GET.
- DELETE: Its only function is to do a destructive operation, not repeatable (once the object  is deleted, there is nothing else to delete).
- PUT: Its function is to modify a single object and update it with the values sent in a POST (like) way. Repeatable.

You can *fake* DELETE and PUT with POST (as some web browsers don't recognize DELETE and PUT).

Please, use GET only to display information, [not for operations with side effects](http://bitworking.org/news/I_m_sorry__I_can_t_kiss_it_and_make_it_better_).

Comment: And by UPDATE, do you mean PUT? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: The word often used is idempotent: repeating the action multiple times results in the same change. GET, PUT and DELETE are all idempotent actions. GET is also safe (it doesn't make any changes). DELETE is idempotent, as deleting the same resource twice still deletes it (although the second request may not 'succeed'. POST requests are not guaranteed to be idempotent, but depending upon the system they may be. If a POST is used for an update, then it may very well be.

Answer (score 4):

In a RESTful architecture, `DELETE` is supposed to be used for requests that will remove data, and `PUT` is supposed to be used for requests that will insert data.

Comment: Thanks, this is already what i know but do they have any advantages rather than using a POST verb for removing data, for example

Comment: POST sends data to code running on a webserver (most commonly, code that generates a webpage). PUT sends data to the webserver software itself.

Comment: There can be only one Chris S here!

Comment: One advantage is that the server-side framework can use the fact that it is a PUT or DELETE request to route the request automatically to the proper controller method, instead of having to specify this in the URL. However, I am not sure if ASP.NET-MVC does this...

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's used to better distinguish actions/privileges.

### Idempotent methods and web applications

> Methods PUT and DELETE are defined to
>   be idempotent, meaning that multiple
>   identical requests should have the
>   same effect as a single request.
>   Methods GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE,
>   being prescribed as safe, should also
>   be idempotent, as HTTP is a stateless
>   protocol. By contrast, the POST method
>   is not necessarily idempotent, and
>   therefore sending an identical POST
>   request multiple times may further
>   affect state or cause further side
>   effects (such as financial
>   transactions). In some cases this may
>   be desirable, but in other cases this
>   could be due to an accident, such as
>   when a user does not realize that
>   their action will result in sending
>   another request, or they did not
>   receive adequate feedback that their
>   first request was successful. While
>   web browsers may show alert dialog
>   boxes to warn users in some cases
>   where reloading a page may re-submit a
>   POST request, it is generally up to
>   the web application to handle cases
>   where a POST request should not be
>   submitted more than once. Note that
>   whether a method is idempotent is not
>   enforced by the protocol or web
>   server. It is perfectly possible to
>   write a web application in which (for
>   example) a database insert or other
>   non-idempotent action is triggered by
>   a GET or other request. Ignoring this
>   recommendation, however, may result in
>   undesirable consequences if a user
>   agent assumes that repeating the same
>   request is safe when it isn't.

via wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check out [BlaM's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343288/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-rest/343306#343306) to this (dupe?) question.

Obviously you can *technically* create/update/delete resources without using REST principles, ut you're missing a point. If you still don't really get the concepts behind REST, [Ryan Tomayko's blog entry](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) is a nice place to start.

Answer (score -3):

The original purpose was to edit webpages using those verbs ([more on the RESTful system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)). They have since been deprecated by the [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) extension. In practice, PUT and DELETE are never used (or very rarely by custom built applications).

Comment: Rarely? Not quite true today with all of those RESTful frameworks out there. And as far as I know they are not deprecated, the WebDAV extension just blocks them on windows for some reason. I am not downvoting you yet, I'm giving you a chance to clarify.

Comment: @the_drow, Yes really. Considering the vast majority of web traffic never comes close to using PUT or DELETE, I'm comfortable in saying that it's very rarely used. The only applications I'm aware of that use PUT or DELETE are data abstraction layers that have nothing to do with browsers or hypertext transport.

Comment: If you are claiming that they are deprecated, why on HTML5 they are added to the form's method attribute? Also you haven't refered to my comment about WebDAV, if it does deprecate PUT and DELETE it is not RESTful and due to that programmers who use asp.net mvc and hope to achieve disable it.

Comment: @The_drow, the original PUT and DELETE commands were replaced in WebDAV. HTML5 is a document language specification with recommendations for the transport, not a communications protocol. I think you misunderstand what a RESTful system is, it does not inherently require PUT and DELETE verbs (either from the original spec, or the WebDAV spec).

Comment: There should be a mean to create and delete then, if there isn't, WebDAV is not RESTful. That's what I meant.