# What does REST mean in real world?

Tags: php, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What am I not understanding about REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343288/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-rest)

I am really confused about REST.What does REST mean in real world?
What does it mean being a RESTful api?
If I write some code in PHP,is it by default RESTful?
Please explain with some examples.

Comment: Google it?! What do you mean with real world? What would be the unreal one?

Comment: To start, you might want to look at [What am I not understanding about REST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343288/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-rest).

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+rest and point out what is still unclear afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a page on it:  [Representational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

From a practical standpoint, it's a way of building a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) by taking advantage of the features of HTTP itself, rather than building a layer on top of HTTP (as [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) does).

Code written in PHP (or any other language) isn't inherently RESTful.  It's a characteristic of how you design your program, not what language you write it in.